# What does "What Mary said!" mean?

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

Here is the situation:

**A**: We love ourselves even after we make so many mistakes, so why do we hate others for one or two mistakes they've made? (sad emotion)

**Mary**: everyone makes mistakes but what is important is knowing to make changes. Can one forgive someone who continues to fault and causes harm to someone else? If one still have trust then one should keep that to be stronger. Always be yourself and don't worry about the results. As long as you are yourself and live your life for you then that is what will give you happiness.

**B** : ***What Mary said*** ! Lucky girl get so many flowers.

Comment: It means "*[I strongly agree with] what Mary [just] said!*".

Comment: No problem. BTW, if you're not a native speaker, and are trying to learn English, you may also enjoy reading our sister site, [ELL.se].

Comment: @DanBron : Oh, this is the first time I know there is this site, thanks. From now, I know where is the right place to ask appropriate questions :)

Comment: Glad you found it useful!  Yes, Google has a strong preference for directing people here, rather than ELL.

Comment: Am I the only person who is completely bewildered by what the OP is asking, and cannot understand how @Dan Bron managed to give such a confident answer?

Comment: @WS2 Well, you and I and OP are the only ones here .. so, yes? Looks like I gave him what he was looking for, anyway. The title of the question was a pretty good hint.

Comment: Something went wrong? ^^

Comment: @WS2 Possibly. It's mostly an internet-generation phrase, and you're more likely to find it on less literate sites than this. There's a useful shorter version, too: *This.*

Comment: @StoneyB Link doesn't work.

Comment: @WS2 No, just the word *This*!

Comment: @StoneyB The recent spates and overuse of  *this* really grinds my gears (as does "*... is everything"). Also, the ungrammatical *because* ("because the internet"). They were all amusing initially, but have long since been run into the ground.

Comment: @DanBron Perhaps it's the sites I visit, but most of the uses of *because X* I see these days are palpably ironic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan Bron said, the phrase `What <name> said!` means that you agree with what they said, or that you would say the exact same thing.

In some cases, this is used by someone who was asked a question, but is interrupted by another person. For example, Johnny asks Wendy, "How could he possibly fly all by himself?!" Bob interjects, saying, "The answer is obviously that the Complex Cortex would display a radical upward shift in quantum possibilities." Wendy, who know nothing about quantum possibilities or the complex cortex, would then say, "What Bob said."

The latter example is, of course, very specific , and generally only happens in conversation.